# Opposite of inequality in SQL -- NOT ( A ≤ B ) =?

Tags: sql, math, logic

Given the SQL statement: NOT (Count ≤ 10) what is it's simplified statement without the NOT.

I could see it being either Count > 10 or Count ≥ 10

Comment: it should be `Count > 10`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Count > 10
```

`Count <= 10` is up to and including 10, while `Count > 10` is everything 11 and over.

Comment: thats what i suspected, overthinking it

Comment: Glad to help, accept the answer if it answered your question

Answer (score 1):

If you are using this value in SQL, then the "functional opposite" would be:

```
(Count > 10 OR Count IS NULL)
```

If you had a `WHERE` clause, then the above would return all rows not returned by the condition in your question.

"Boolean" logic in SQL is a bit complicated, because it is a three-part logic with true, false, and `NULL`.  `NULL` fails basically all comparisons, so it fails `NOT (Count >= 10)` *and* it fails `(Count < 10)`.

I should note as well that `Count` is the name of an aggregation function, so it is a bad choice for a column name.

Comment: Do non-Oracle dialects have analogue of `lnnvl`?

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff . . . The ASCII standard is `is not distinct from`.  MySQL has an operator `<=>`.  Other databases may have similar constructs, although SQL Server does not.